# quartz job fires even though scheduled time has passed

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am using a Quartz scheduler using java.
Even though the scheduled time has passed, it does not throw a scheduler exception and instead runs the job now..FOr example I confirgured a Job for October10th and today it October 30th, If I save the information, it runs the job now itself

Also I am using JobListener implementation to manually fire a job to schedule it later in case some other job is running at the same point in time.

Please help.

Comment: We'll be able to help you better if you include some code.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is configured in the trigger misfire instructions. The default instruction depends on the trigger type. You can set the misfire instruction at the scheduleBuilder:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
    .startAt(new Date(2014,10,10))
    .withSchedule(withIntervalInMonths(1)
        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Done, just added a check for time before scheduling  the job whether the scheduled time has passed the current time or not

```
Date startTime = cal.getTime();
//Check if the Scheduled time has passed or not
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentTime = currentCal.getTime();    
if(!(currentTime.compareTo(startTime)>0)){
  scheduler.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
}
```